# Como faço para "capturar" a rota completa de uma chamada http com express router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, router

Estou utilizando o `express.router` aninhando a minha rota em vários "router.use()". É possível pegar a rota final via console?

ex:

```
const routes = Router();
const v1Router = Router();
const enggajadoresRouter = Router();

routes.use('/v1', V1Router);
v1Router.use('/usuarios', UsuariosRouter);
UsuarioRouter.post('/', usuariosControllers.create);
```

nesse caso a minha rota post será localhost:3000/v1/usuarios/

preciso de um meio em que eu consiga pegar o valor: '/v1/usuarios/'

Answer (score 4):

#### Para obter o caminho da requisição

Utilize a propriedade `path`. Da [documentação](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path):

```
// https://example.com/users?sort=desc

console.dir(req.path);
//=> '/users'
```

#### Para obter o URL completo

1. Utilizar [`req.protocol`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) para obter o protocolo da requisição, como `http` ou `https`;
2. Utilizar [`req.get('host')`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) para obter o *host* da requisição;
3. O caminho pode ser obtido com [`req.originalUrl`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html). Note que a propriedade `originalUrl` também inclui os *query parameters*, então dependendo do propósito pode não ser o que você quer.

Desse modo, para montar o URL completo, pode concatenar as partes para montar a string completa. Assim:

```
// https://example.com/users?sort=desc

const fullURL = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}${req.originalUrl}`;
console.log(fullURL);
//=> https://example.com/users?sort=desc
```

Inspirado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183291/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-express) do Stack Overflow em Inglês.